# What does the $\wedge$-symbol mean in academic papers?

Tags: notation, definition

For instance, here's definition 16 of the Ethereum [Yellow Paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf):

[image: Yellow Paper Defintion]

Does $\wedge$ simply mean a concatenation of statements? Like the logic gate AND?

Comment: Its the AND statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\wedge$ is *exactly* 'and' in this context. $\vee$ means 'or'. You can notice the similarity both in form and meaning with $\cap$ and $\cup$ from set theory.

In differential geometry, $\omega_1\wedge\omega_2$ also means the wedge product of two differential forms.

Answer (score 5):

$\wedge$ is (most often) the mathematical symbol for [logical conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction), which is equivalent to the AND operator you're used to.

Similarly $\vee$ is  (most often) [logical disjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction), which would be equivalent to the OR operator.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this symbol is generally used to denote AND. See the wikipedia article on [Logical Conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction):

> $ A\land B$ is true only if $A$ is true and $B$ is true

Similarly, we use $ A\lor B$ to mean $A$ OR $B$ (logical disjunction).